# emberjs record.save() throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, django-rest-framework

am having an issue where my emberjs on record.save() is throwing

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null"

here is my code

```
App.Signup = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string')
});

App.SignupController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
actions: {
    cliky: function() {
        var sElement = this.store.createRecord('signup', {
            email: "test",
            password: "test1",
        }).save();
    },
}
});
```

fixed the bottom errors with the fixed response on the server side ( i hardcoded for testing). but the information comming from Emberjs is null!

I am using the Django rest framework and when i do print request.DATA it is 'none'...

So am i printing something wrong from django?

Comment: Can you add the json response from the server when you save?

Comment: updated the post for you.

Comment: So I don't use django's rest framework, but I do use django with an ember app, and I am pulling the data from the body, `data = simplejson.loads(request.body)`

Comment: Can you add a stack trace from the error? Also, are you just using the default RestAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that Ember expect to receive the persisted record in return. 
This is because often you add fields to the property server site, like id, created_at, updated_at, and Ember want to update the frontend record with the returned data. When you return null, Ember doesn't know how to map it.

You can do a test drive by returning

```
{
   signups: {
     id: 1,
     email: "test",
     password: "test1"
   }
}
```